# Are special antennas required for 802.11n connection?

Tags: wifi

I'm looking for a chip or a PCB antenna to add to a module. I would like if there's difference between antennas that make some suitable for 802.11n WiFi connection and some to 802.11b/g.

Comment: what is a special antenna, anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Antennas do have a bandwidth; for example, an FM Radio antenna will only efficiently cover around 80 – 110 MHz. If you wanted to listen to a signal that is broader than those 30 MHz, you'd need a different antenna.

802.11n does have 40 MHz channels instead of only the 20 MHz of a/g, but devices for WiFi don't just cover a single 20 MHz channel – they need to work on all WiFi channels, and thus, they are far, far broader from the start.

Comment: While it might look obvious, I'd still like to point out that this answer is going to be valid only if we're going to be using the 2.4 GHz band.